# gambio gx2 module implementation. Filename CONSTANT

Tags: php, module, gambio

I have got problems to Implement my own Module, wich I want to develop.

My Steps:

1. in `/admin/includes/application_top.php` + `define('FILENAME_MYMODULE', 'test_mymodule.php');`
2. `/lang/german/admin/gm_german.php` + `define('BOX_MYMODULE', 'MyModule');`
3. `/lang/german/sections/_samples/admin_menu.lang.inc.php` + `'BOX_MYMODULE' => 'MyModule',`
4. ``` INSERT INTO ``gm_lang_files_content`` VALUES('', 246, 'BOX_MYMODULE', 'MyModule'); ```
5. `/system/conf/AdminMenu/gambio_menu.xml` + `<menuitem sort="10" link="FILENAME_MYMODULE" title="{$txt.BOX_MYMODULE}" />`

Now my Problem is, when I clear the cache and reload, I didn't see my menu option.
If I change test_mymodule.php in gm_ebay.php or somethink else it will work.

Why it dosent work with my file?

I would be extremely grateful for your help

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution, i think some newbie like me in gambio search it to.

last point insert in database
ALTER TABLE `admin_access` ADD `myfile` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';

and update it to 1 for true

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution to stay updateable:

Menu entry:
/user_classes/conf/admin_menu/menu_mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- {load_language_text section="admin_menu"} -->
<admin_menu>
    <menugroup id="BOX_HEADING_IMPORT_EXPORT">
        <menuitem sort="10" link="mymodule.php" link_param="your=param" title="MyModule" />
    </menugroup>
</admin_menu>
```

Create /admin/includes/modules/mymodule/css/mymodule_backend.css

Create /admin/includes/modules/mymodule/index.php

```
<?php
$string =  '<td class="boxCenter" width="100%" valign="top">

<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="pageHeading" style="background-image: url(images/icons/amicicard_30.png);float:left;">&nbsp;MyModule</td>
            <td class="pageHeading" align="right"><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="HEADING_IMAGE_WIDTH" height="HEADING_IMAGE_HEIGHT"></td>
          </tr>
</table>

<span class="main">
';


echo $string;

echo "Do your work here like that.<br>";
echo "You can include classes etc. in here and use echo as output.";

echo '</div>';
```

Create /admin/mymodule.php

```
    <?php
$version = phpversion();
$majorVersion = explode('.', $version);
$majorVersion = intval($majorVersion[0]);

if ($majorVersion < 5)
{
    return;
}

require('includes/application_top.php');
$isPopup = isset($_GET['popup']) ? true : false;

?>
    <!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html <?php echo HTML_PARAMS; ?>>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo $_SESSION['language_charset']; ?>">
        <title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/modules/mymodule/css/mymodule_backend.css">

    </head>
    <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<?php

if (!$isPopup)
{
    //include header:
    require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'header.php');

    //include body:
    echo '<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td class="columnLeft2" width="'.BOX_WIDTH.'" valign="top"><table border="0" width="'.BOX_WIDTH.'" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="columnLeft">';

    //include left navigation:
    require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'column_left.php');

    echo '</table></td>';
}
else
{
    //include body:
    echo '<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td class="columnLeft2" width="100%" valign="top"><table border="0" width="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="columnLeft">';

}

require_once('./includes/modules/mymodule/index.php');

echo '</tr></table>';




if (!$isPopup)
{
    //footer:
    require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'footer.php');
}

echo '<br>
      </body>
      </html>';

require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'application_bottom.php');
?>
```

Update your Database like mentioned by user unfair

> last point insert in database ALTER TABLE admin_access ADD myfile INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
>
> and update it to 1 for true

Thats it.

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT4iV.png)