# How to create and new module in admin side in Gambio?

Tags: php, module, gambio

I already did the steps from this link with [basic steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147730/gambio-gx2-module-implementation-filename-constant) + some adjustments to the new version of Gambio.

My problem is that now in my admin/Module menu I cannot see my created module "MyModule", but if I access the page website/admin/mymodule.php it works.

Could someone confirm the steps in the link? Or better guide me from start to end what do you have to add/modify in gambio to add a new module.

Thanks!

LE: I came across this link [Gambio language docs (german)](https://tracker.gambio-server.net/projects/gxdoc/wiki/Sprachdateien_erstellen) where some things about the language are explained! I hope this will help future developers!

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it's like in the provided link with some small changes.
1st step it's fine

2nd step doesn't work for me. I tried {$txt.BOX_TESTMODULE} in a new menu_testmodule.xml where gambio_menu.xml is and {$txt.BOX_TESTMODULE} direct in gambio_menu.xml and doesn't work. So I just wrote direct "TestModule" - but this will affect the language change. Note that I added BOX_TESTMODULE in all the following: lang/eng(or german)/sections/_samples/admin_menu.lang.in.php and in the lang_english(or german)_admin_gm_english__php.lang.inc.php and my menu didn't show up when I added this changes.

Steps 3 and 4 didn't influenced that much anything.

Step 5 didn't work with the {$txt.BOX_TESTMODULE} so I wrote directly "TestModule' and now shows the module in menu.

Step 6 that is not there, but is an extra step that should clean the cache to see the modules. You can do that from the admin side of the website in the toolbox menu.

And somewhere in between (step 2-4) should be another step from the comments to add in the db, in the access_admin the new menu entry (testmodule in my case) and update it to 1 (to give access).

If someone has another experience with the language detection part ({$txt.BOX_TESTMODULE}) please leave a comment.